# Can I return to Canada after being ordered to depart?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

My family was issued a departure notice of 30 days from the Canadian immigration when I was 10 years old.  We relocated back to our country 15 years ago.

I am now married and my wife wants to go to Ottawa to see her sick grandmother before she passes away.  She would like the kids to see her.

Will I be able to get a visitors visa because of that departure notice. Kindly note my family paid for our own trip,  and we were cleared by immigration at the border;  we also left within the stipulated time.

Should I apply for an ARC (authorization to return to Canada) or am I exempted from it since I was a minor at that time?

Answer (score 3):

If you left within the 30 days you do not require an ARC. ARCs are only needed if you have had a deportation order or an exclusion order (if you wish to return before the 2/5 year ban period).

The circumstances that lead to your departure order will be considered when your application is assessed but I doubt it will have an impact on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you would need to apply would depend on type of order you and your family were issued. Although you were a minor, you were still subject to the removal, and would want to check whether [Authorization to return to Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/inadmissibility/reasons/authorization-return-canada.html) is required. If you're unsure or don't have a copy of the document, it would be advisable to request authorization.

> **Types of removal orders**
>
> There are three types of removal orders.
>
> Look at the document you received from us before you left Canada. The form number will tell you the type of removal order.
>
> **1. Departure Order (form number IMM 5238)**
>
> a. If you received a Departure Order and
>
> **⇨** left Canada within the required 30 days and
>   **⇨** verified your departure with a Canadian immigration officer at the port of exit
>   you do not need an ARC. You may return to Canada subject to normal examination at the port of entry.
>
> b. If you left the country without verifying your departure, or more than 30 days after the Departure Order was issued, the Departure Order automatically becomes a Deportation Order and you need to apply for an ARC (see point 3 below).
>
> **2. Exclusion Order (form number IMM 1214B)**
>
> a. If you were issued an Exclusion Order and
>
> **⇨** 12 months have passed since you left Canada and
>   **⇨** you have a Certificate of Departure (IMM 0056B) showing the date you left Canada
>   you do not need an ARC. You may return to Canada subject to normal examination at the port of entry.
>
> b. If you wish to return to Canada less than 12 months after the Exclusion Order was issued, or do not have a Certificate of Departure, you need to apply for an ARC.
>
> **3. Deportation Order (form number IMM 5238B)**
>
> If you have been the subject of a Deportation Order you will need to apply for an ARC.
>
> **Note:** A Direction to Leave Canada (form number IMM 1217B) is not a removal order. If you have been the subject of a Direction to Leave Canada, you do not need to apply for an ARC. You may return to Canada subject to normal examination at the port of entry.

Comment: If she was given a 30 day time to depart it was obviously a departure order. If she applied for a visa and an ARC is needed she will be informed. No need to spend so much money if she's unsure.